# Prevent back navigation on prism navigation?

Tags: xamarin, prism

I'm trying to prevent the user from back navigation on prism xamarin forms.

I'm having difficulty because, when I get the event, the app changes the page.

How do I block back navigation on prism navigation?

Comment: Attempted to clarify question

Comment: Sorry, Will I need cancel the back navigation on Xamarin Forms with prism, just it

Answer (score -1):

You can try to intercept the back event. One way is to implement the interface INavigationAware in your ViewModel:

```
public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
{
   if(parameters.GetNavigationMode()== NavigationMode.Back){
      //Here your code
   }
}
```

Or take a look to this discussion:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18565/override-cancel-pop-when-hardware-back-button-pressed-using-navigatepage

Comment: Yes, but, OnNavigatedTo is a void method and it doesn't cancel the back navigation :/

Comment: I edited my answer with a link that can be useful for you.